# coroutines behave differently on Android/JVM (for windows)

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm, kotlin-coroutines

I'm creating a second version of an Android/Windows remote control app using kotlin for client and server. I'm familiar with the basics of coroutines on android but to my surprise/unfortunateness, coroutines have behaved differently on the two platforms. I tested the EXACT same code and on android it just works but on the computer nothing happens

> **Main.kt**

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {

    CoroutineScope(Job()).launch {
        println("connecting server")
        Servidor.ligar()
    }

    CoroutineScope(Job()).launch {
        println("connecting client")
        Cliente.ligar()

    }

}
```

> **Server.kt**

```
object Servidor {

    suspend fun ligar() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val porta = 1777
        var mensagem: String

        val server = ServerSocket(porta)
        println("Trying to connect through $porta...")

        val client = server.accept()
        val mPrintWriter = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)

        val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))
        println("Connected by port: $porta")

        while (br.readLine().also { mensagem = it } != null) {
            println("The message: $mensagem")
            if (mensagem == "bye") {
                mPrintWriter.println("bye")
                break
            } else {
                mensagem = "Server returns $mensagem"
                mPrintWriter.println(mensagem)
            }
        }
        mPrintWriter.close()
        br.close()

        client.close()
    }
}
```

> **Client.kt**

```
object Cliente {

    suspend fun ligar() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

        val portNumber = 1777
        var str = "initialize"

        val mSocket = Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNumber)
        val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(mSocket.getInputStream()))
        val pw = PrintWriter(mSocket.getOutputStream(), true)

        pw.println(str)
        println(str)

        while (br.readLine().also { str = it } != null) {
            println(str)
            pw.println("bye")
            if (str == "bye") break
        }
        br.close()
        pw.close()
        mSocket.close()
    }

}
```

The code for client/server connection works perfectly, when executed from an activity in android.

This is the output from Logcat when the code is run on android (Android Studio):

```
connecting server
connecting client
Trying to connect through 1777...
initialize
Connected by port: 1777
The message: initialize
Server returns initialize
The message: bye
bye
```

This is the Logcat output when the code is run on windows (Intellij IDEA)

```
connecting server
calling customer

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm clearly not knowing how to deal with coroutines outside the android environment, how can i make this work as intended?

Ps: Here is the list of libraries i'm using on desktop version on app:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4
```

Comment: Your log is showing an output line that doesn't exist in the code you posted.  So something isn't wired the way you think it is

Comment: Remove `CoroutineScope(Job()).` in main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not waiting for your launched coroutines. When you are in a `runBlocking`, it only blocks to wait for it’s launched children. But you are creating new CoroutineScopes for launching coroutines, so they are not children of the `runBlocking` coroutine. They are fired off asynchronously. Then `runBlocking` returns and your app terminates immediately.